# How to not request certain properties when creating an object through SOAP?

Tags: java, soap, cxf

Assume I have an User object:

```
public class User {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String surname;

// getters + setters

}
```

When creating a User through SOAP, I want the user to input only the name and surname but not the id. In this case, should I create something like UserDTO object? For example:

```
public class UserDTO {

private String name;
private String surname;

// getters + setters

}
```

In my service bean, I will have the following method:

```
public void updateUser (Long id, UserDTO dto) {
User user = new User(id, dto.getName(), dto.getSurname());
service.updateUser(user);
}
```

Will this be a correct approach to my question? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question right but why don't you just provide second constructor for your `User` class?

It will be:

```
public class User {

   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;

   //in case of creating user manually
   public User(Long id, String name, String surname) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
   }
   //in case of creating user via soap:
   public User(String name, String surname) {
       this.id = generateId(); //or some other logic to specify users id
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
   }
}
```